# Return file handle from subroutine and pass to other subroutine

Tags: perl, filehandle

I am trying to create a couple of functions that will work together. `getFH` should take in the mode to open the file (either `>` or `<` ), and then the file itself (from the command line). It should do some checking to see if the file is okay to open, then open it, and return the file handle. `doSomething` should take in the file handle, and loop over the data and do whatever. However when the program lines to the while loop, I get the error:

> readline() on unopened filehandle 1

What am I doing wrong here?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;

# command line param(s)
my $infile = '';
my $usage = "\n\n$0 [options] \n
Options
-infile         Infile
-help           Show this help message
\n";

# check flags
GetOptions(
    'infile=s' => \$infile,
    help       => sub { pod2usage($usage) },
) or pod2usage(2);

my $inFH = getFh('<', $infile);

doSomething($inFH);

## Subroutines ##

## getFH ##
## @params:
## How to open file: '<' or '>'
## File to open

sub getFh {
    my ($read_or_write, $file) = @_;
    my $fh;

    if ( ! defined $read_or_write ) {
        die "Read or Write symbol not provided", $!;
    }

    if ( ! defined $file ) {
        die "File not provided", $!;
    }

    unless ( -e -f -r -w $file ) {
        die "File $file not suitable to use", $!;
    }

    unless ( open( $fh, $read_or_write, $file ) ) {
        die "Cannot open $file",$!;
    }

    return($fh);
}

#Take in filehandle and do something with data

sub doSomething{
    my $fh = @_;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        say $_;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my $fh = @_;
```

This line does not mean what you think it means.  It sets `$fh` to *the number of items in `@_`* rather than the filehandle that is passed in - if you print the value of `$fh`, it will be `1` instead of a filehandle.

Use `my $fh = shift`, `my $fh = $_[0]`, or `my ($fh) = @_` instead.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple like that. Thanks @Dave Sherohman, still getting comfortable with Perl again. Being programming in R all summer

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, `my $fh = @_` will set `$fh` to 1, which is not a file handle. Use

```
my ($fh) = @_
```

instead to use list assignment

In addition

- `-e -f -r -w $file` will not do what you want. You need

  ```
  -e $file and -f $file and -r $file and -w $file
  ```

  And you can make this more concise and efficient by using underscore `_` in place of the file name, which will re-use the information fetched for the previous file test

  ```
  -e $file and -f _ and -r _ and -w _
  ```

  However, note that you will be rejecting a request if a file isn't *writeable*, which makes no sense if the request is to open a file for reading. Also, `-f` will return *false* if the file doesn't exist, so `-e` is superfluous
- It is good to include `$!` in your `die` strings as it contains the *reason* for the failure, but your first two tests don't set this value up, and so should be just `die "Read or Write symbol not provided";` etc.

  In addition, `die "Cannot open $file", $!` should probably be

  ```
  die qq{Cannot open "$file": $!}
  ```

  to make it clear if the file name is empty, and to add some space between the message and the value of `$!`
- The lines read from the file will have a newline character at the end, so there is no need for `say`. Simply `print while <$fh>` is fine
- Perl variable names are conventionally *snake_case*, so `get_fh` and `do_something` is more usual

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Borodin ! Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Dave it's fixed